# How can I disable suggested meetings in Microsoft Outlook for Mac?

Tags: ms-office

Outlook for Mac (the application, not the online version) is highlighting "Suggested Meetings" in my emails and turning them into a link to a calendar invite. I find this annoying and inaccurate, but can't find any way to turn it off. How can I do so?

Outlook for Mac v16.25, running on macOS Mojave.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not certain of what other side effects might happen, but I've found that by going to `Preferences > Privacy` and unselecting **Enable Optional connected experiences** Outlook has stopped showing those annoying underlines.